# Was für ein Wort beschreibt, wie einschüchternd eine Person ist?

Tags: noun, synonym

Ich möchte Charaktere anhand von wenigen Eigenschaften beschreiben (in der Form `Eigenschaft: Wert`).

Ich finde jedoch kein gutes Wort, um darzustellen, wie einschüchternd/furchterregend/bedrohlich eine Person erscheinen kann. Bisher nutze ich *Einschüchterung*, aber dieses Wort klingt furchtbar.

Andere Eigenschaften, welche ich beispielsweise verwende, sind:

- Mut
- Glück
- Klugheit
- Intuition
- Gewandtheit
- Feinmotorik
- Sympathie
- *Einschüchterung*
- Stärke
- Konstitution

Wie man an der Liste sieht, fällt *Einschüchterung* etwas aus der Reihe. :(

Comment: wie wäre Imposanz?

Comment: Ich finde Eigenschaften ist hier das falsche Wort. Man kann "mutig sein" und "sympathisch sein" und "stark sein" (--> Charaktereigenschaften), aber man "hat Glück" oder "hat eine gute Konstitution". Ich würde übrigens auch Feinmotorik durch Geschicklichkeit ersetzen.

Comment: @Iris Ich glaube, mit _Glück_ ist hier nicht _luckiness_ (beim Lotto-Spielen), sondern _happiness_ (über die eigene Situation) gemeint.

Comment: @PerlDog nicht sicher - es scheint sich hier um den Charakterbogen bei einer Art Rollenspiel zu handeln, da sehe ich "Glücklichsein" als unwichtiger als "Glück haben"

Comment: Ja @PerlDog hat recht, es handelt sich um die Eigenschaften eines Rollenspiel Charakters. Vielen Dank auch schon mal für die vielen Vorschläge. Ich werde aber noch etwas Zeit brauchen bis ich mich entscheide.

Comment: @Iris: Ist "hat eine gute Konstitution" nicht nur eine geläufigere Formulierung für "ist mit einer guten Konstitution ausgestattet/versehen/gesegnet/..."? Entsprechendes lässt sich auch bei "Glück haben" sagen, wenn man von einer Welt ausgeht, in der Glück eine messbare Größe ist. Das klingt also durchaus nach Eigenschaften (wenn auch nicht notwendigerweise nach Charaktereigenschaften - Charakter im Sinn der immateriellen Persönlichkeit), beziehungsweise danach, als könnten hier nicht sinnvoll zwei oder mehr Gruppen von Messgrößen ("Eigenschaften" und ... "andere") unterschieden werden.

Answer (score 8):

Ich glaube, du suchst nach sowas wie

- Überzeugungskraft
- Führungskompetenz
- Charisma
- Präsenz
- Autorität

(Das letzte Wort passt m.A. nach am besten, möglicherweise ergänzt zu "natürliche Autorität")

Comment: Dominanz wäre auch noch eine Variante

Comment: @Falco Darüber habe ich nachgedacht. *Dominanz* ist allerdings eher eine Folge aus *Aktivitäten* der Person als eine inhärente Eigenschaft. Bedeutungsüberlappungen sind zwar da, aber nur teilweise.

Answer (score 3):

Noch viel schlimmer als `Einschüchterung`, aber trotzdem mMn besser passend wäre `Einschüchterungspotential`.

Etwas besser in den Kontext passt aber u.U. der Begriff `Bedrohlichkeit`

Answer (score 1):

Eigenschaften, die einen einschüchternd wirken lassen, sind vielleicht auch:

- Macht
- Überlegenheit
- Selbstbewusstsein
- Herrschaft
- Entschlossenheit
- Aggressivität
- Wut